# reactjs.net - are react-text tags required when rendered?

Tags: reactjs.net

I have been following this tutorial http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html and all works great. However in the final output source, I get the following comment tags, why is the text wrapped around the `react-text` tags, are they required tags? Why are they in comment tags? Can they be removed somehow?

```
<!-- react-text: 6 -->Hello ReactJS.NET World!<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 9 -->This is one comment<!-- /react-text -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are needed, they're used internally by React to denote segments of text. For example, if you render two variables directly next to each other, React uses the comments to know where one variable ends and the next variable begins, so it can correctly update the text on updates.

This was changed in React v15, previous versions used `<span>`s to wrap the text segments. There's more information at https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html#no-more-extra-ltspangts.

Comment: I used to avoid these when outputting strings with multiple rendered values by react, by using es6 interpolation instead. But if a render call needs to update only one value of several in a string, it is preferable to let react handle the value update using comment marks, instead of taking a slight performance hit with the interpolation of all values.